# Docker Nginx+Railsでサーバ起動すると502 Bad Gatewayになる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx

Docker(CentOS7)でnginxとrailsの構築をしています。

Nginxコンテナとrailsコンテナをそれぞれ起動し、ソケット通信を利用してMacOSのChromeでアクセスしたいのですが、
ソケット通信がうまくいっていないのか、`localhost:8080`にアクセスすると`502 Bad Gateway`エラーになる状況です。

アクセス後のnginxのエラー（/var/log/nginx/error）

```
2020/04/27 06:45:32 [error] 125#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.25.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "localhost:8080"
2020/04/27 06:45:32 [warn] 125#0: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 172.25.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "localhost:8080"
2020/04/27 06:45:32 [error] 125#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.25.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "localhost:8080"
2020/04/27 06:45:32 [warn] 125#0: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 172.25.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "localhost:8080"
2020/04/27 06:45:33 [error] 125#0: *1 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 172.25.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://localhost/favicon.ico", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/"
2020/04/27 06:47:36 [error] 127#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.25.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "localhost:8080"
2020/04/27 06:47:38 [error] 127#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.25.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/"
```

下記にあるnginx.confのソースコードの通り、色々試してみたのですが、うまくいかず、どのように設定すれば正常にアクセスできるのか悩んでいます。
解決策をご教授いただけると幸いです。

- pumaを使用しています。
- `/tmp/sockets/server.pid`のマウント設定もdocker-compose.ymlで設定しています。
- railsはポート番号5000で起動しています。

## ソースコード

nginx.conf

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error warn;

worker_processes 2;
worker_rlimit_nofile 150000;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  upstream testdocker {
    server unix:///var/www/testdocker/tmp/pids/server.pid;
    # 試したコード
    # server localhost:5000;
    # server 127.0.0.1:5000;
    # server 0.0.0.0:5000;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1:8000;
    # 試したコード
    # listen 8080;
    # server_name localhost;
    # server_name testdocker;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      # proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; # 試したコード
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  rails:
    build: .
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
     - ./testdocker:/var/www/testdocker
    working_dir: /var/www/testdocker
    command: >
      bash -c "rails s -b 0.0.0.0;
      bash"
    ports:
      - '5000:3000'

  nginx:
    build: .
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    privileged: true
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx.repo:/etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
      - ./testdocker/tmp/pids:/var/www/testdocker/tmp/pids # server.pidをマウントする
    command: /sbin/init
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

Docker

```
FROM centos:7.7.1908

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV TZ Asia/Tokyo
ENV LC_ALL=C

# 必要なパッケージをインストール
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum install -y git tzdata libxml2-devel.x86_64 libcurl-devel.x86_64 gcc-c++.x86_64 glibc-devel.x86_64 mariadb-devel.x86_64 ImageMagick.x86_64 bzip2 make which epel-release gmp-devel.x86_64

# NodeJSのインストール
RUN curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN yum install -y nodejs

# rubyとrailsをインストール
RUN git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build && PREFIX=/usr/local ./ruby-build/install.sh && rm -rf ruby-build
RUN ruby-build 2.7.1 /usr/local
RUN gem install -v 5.2.4 rails --no-document

# Gemfileのインストール
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/testdocker
WORKDIR /var/www/testdocker
COPY /testdocker/Gemfile Gemfile
COPY /testdocker/Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install

# Nigixのインストール
COPY nginx.repo ./etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
RUN yum install -y nginx
```

## バージョン

nginx 1.16.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rails コンテナ内部から見ると 3000 番ポートで起動していて、ホストの 5000 番ポートからポートフォワードしているのですよね？

もし、そうならば、nginx コンテナからは、ホストの 5000 番ポートではなく、rails コンテナの 3000 番ポートに接続するよう、`proxy_pass` を設定する必要があります。

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://rails:3000;
    (略)
}
```

ただし、nginx コンテナから "rails" で名前解決するには、[links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links) で設定するか、[networks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#networks) で両コンテナを同じネットワークに配置するか、どちらかになると思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
`proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;`と設定したのですが、変わりませんでした。
networkやlinksについて調べてみたところ、docker-composeで起動している場合は自動で設定されるようです。

Comment: proxy_passにあるrailsはサービス名だったんですね。`rails:3000`としたところうまく接続されました。先ほどのコメントは失礼しました。networkやlinksについては設定する必要はありませんでした。